# Information is not saved to a file during a power outage

Tags: java, android, io, bufferedreader, android-file

There are two methods, one for writing a line to a file, the other for reading.

```
public void onSaveButtonClick(View view) {
String text = binding.etSave.getText().toString();
if (text.isEmpty()) {
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.empty_text_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}

File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), FILE_NAME);      
try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
    writer.write(text);
    Log.d("logtest write", text);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

public void onReadButtonClick(View view) {
File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), FILE_NAME);      
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    String text = reader.readLine();
    Log.d("logtest read", text);
    binding.etLoad.setText(text);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

I'm conducting an experiment, writing new data to a file, subtracting it from a file, and **seeing new data**. I turn off the battery, reconnect, start the device and software, read the data - **the data is old**. No new data has been saved.

As I understand, at the first reading I get cached data that the OS does not have time to physically record due to an emergency power outage. Am I right or not? And how can I solve this problem?

Comment: have you tried adding `writer.flush()` after `writer.write(...)` call?

Comment: Yes, it didn’t help

Comment: `writer.close();` is missing.

Comment: And `reader.close();` is missing.

Comment: Is used try-with-resources

Comment: ???? What did you mean?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: reader and writer are closed

Comment: so, you say SharedPreferences work... does it work with `.apply()` or `.commit()` ? if `.apply()` doesn't work then i suspect it's the async writing that's the real problem (similar to a missing flush, which is similar to `.commit()`)

Comment: Strange, now I checked and doesn't work not with apply and not with commit. Although it used to work. I will remove this statement from the description.